# If a user has accepted T&Cs but have not 'enrolled' then do we need them to accept again?

Tags: usability, terms-of-service

So I am working on a product that has multiple steps for enrolment. The first step is to accept T&Cs. Our current workflow is such that if the user has accepted t&cs and then they leave the enrolment flow halfway, the next time they come back they will not be prompted to accept the T&Cs again.

My question is is that the best UX approach? Or should we surface T&Cs again?

On one hand they have already accepted so it's just adding extra friction. But on the other hand they may have done it a while ago and forgotten that they did.

Any advice is helpful!

Answer (score 2):

From a usability, development, and legal standpoint, **it is advisable to display the terms and conditions again**.

**Usability reasons:** Users may not recall what they previously agreed to, and some might have overlooked the T&C altogether. If users failed to complete the user journey at first, it suggests a potential issue. Additionally, what happens if users actually look for the T&C?

**Legal:** Without users completing the entire process and submitting their information along with a timestamp, their agreement to the terms cannot be legally established. Since you presented the T&C as an initial step, users maybe found reasons to discontinue their engagement, which is something you should investigate.

**Development:** Modifying the current UI to conditionally hide the display of T&C requires additional development time and increases [**UX debt**](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ux-debt/). However, leaving the existing UI untouched would resolve this matter easily.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that if they have already accepted the T&Cs it might add a bit of friction to re-ping them about this, and it might also confuse them: if they remember signing them before, they could wonder if something has changed or why they are being asked again. You could maybe set a timestamp and send a notification to users who rejoin the enrolment after x amount of months that represents a long time, and not the ones who take a shorter break, but if they have already accepted the T&Cs and no changes have been made, I would say you're good :)